# treemap aggregate values which are too small to be visualized correctly

Tags: d3.js, treemap

so I've started using d3 treemap, and of course it's great.
problem is- some of my data has very large size, and some very small size (i.e `{ name: 'j', size: 5000} , { name: 'x', size: 15}` etc...).
So the result visualization of course shows several very large cells and some very small ones.
on the small cells, the text is not visible at all, so they're not very usable.

I was wondering if there's an option to aggregate all small value cells to one 'others' cell?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no option to do this automatically. You have to do the aggregation manually. The code could look something like this.

```
var bigEnough = data.filter(function(d) { return d.size >= threshold; }),
    tooSmall = data.filter(function(d) { return d.size < threshold; }),
    nodes = bigEnough.push({name: 'other',
                            size: d3.sum(tooSmall, function(d) { return d.size; })
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of scaling your values as you feed them into your treemap function, to whatever extent you see fit. It would deform the perception of the smallest values, but it would help to keep everything visible. I'd start by looking at your max and min and gauging a good mean term. You can try at [linear](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-_linear) or [log](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-_log) scale.

```
var dataScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d){return d.size}),
         d3.max(data, function(d){return d.size})]);



dataScale.range([0,100]); //here you can choose a hard coded amount, 
                   //or quartiles of your data to fit your needs

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { return dataScale(d.size); });
```